# Context html export garbles bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, context, html

I added `\setupbackend[export=yes]` to my file to test the html export capabilities. All works excellent except the bibliography which is either split (in `-div` version) or comes as one paragraph (in `-tag` or `-raw` versions. Obviously there is just one line that needs to be added so that each bibliography entry was considered as a paragraph.

```
\setuplanguage[en]
\setupbackend[export=yes]
\mainlanguage[english]

\startbuffer[bib]

@Book{Declercq:2000,
  author      = {Declercq, Georges},
  title       = {Anno Domini: The origins of the Christian era},
  address     = {Turnhout},
  publisher   = {Brill},
  year        = {2000},
  shorttitle = {Anno Domini},
  shorthand = {Declercq},
  language    = {english},
  hyphenation = {english},
  pagetotal   = {206},
}

@Book{Rupke:2011,
author = {Jörg Rupke},
title = {The Roman Calendar from Numa to Constantine: Time, History, and the Fasti},
address = {Chichester, West Sussex, U.K.},
publisher = {Wiley-Blackwell},
year = {2011},
shorttitle = {The Roman Calendar},
shorthand = {The Roman calendar},
language = {english},
hyphenation = {english},
}

\stopbuffer

\usebtxdataset[default][bib.buffer]
\loadbtxdefinitionfile[apa]
\usebtxdefinitions[apa]
\setupbtx[dataset=default]
\definebtxrendering[default][apa][specification=chicago,sorttype=authoryear,numbering=no]
\setupindenting[big,yes]
\usetypescript[palatino]
\setupbodyfont[palatino,12pt]

\starttext

\startbodymatter

Test.\cite[Rupke:2011] Another test.\cite[Declercq:2000]

\stopbodymatter

\startbackmatter
\startchapter[title=Bibliography]
\placelistofpublications[criterium=all]
\stopchapter
\stopbackmatter

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run `context <file>.tex` with the option `\setupbackend[export=yes]`, you will get the following structure:

```
<file>-export
├── <file>-div.html
├── <file>-pub.lua
├── <file>-raw.xml
├── <file>-tag.xhtml
├── images
└── styles
    ├── <file>-defaults.css
    ├── <file>-images.css
    ├── <file>-styles.css
    └── <file>-templates.css
```

You can add space between the bibliography entries, by setting the `margin` with the following snippet:

```css
listitem[detail=btx-apa],
div.listitem.btx-apa {
    display: block ;
    margin : 2ex ;
}
```

There are two ways how to do that:

1. After running `context <file>.tex` you can add the snippet to `<file>-style.css` file in the `styles`.
2. You can create a new css-file, `<cssfile>.css`, which contains your own settings (like the snippet above) and specify it with `\setupexport[cssfile=<cssfile>.css]` in your document, and run `context <file>.tex` afterwards.

Both ways will result in separated paragraphs:

[image]

The second way has the advantage, that you can collect all your css stylings in one place and (re)use them for different documents.

Comment: Just to clarify: `\setupexport[cssfile=PaperName.css]` is what you mean? Or `\setupexport[cssfile=PaperName-style.css]`?

Comment: @DmitryStarostin See my edit